# Saving a selected value in gridview to viewstate

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to capture and save the selected value in a gridview to a variable in viewstate which i would like to use to pass as a query string parameter to a differant page

Where would i save the ViewState Variable and how?

Iam very new and not usre whether i have provided enough information

Thanks

Comment: Why does it need to go into viewstate if you're just going to pass it as a query string parameter?

Comment: you should consider accept some answers, as you have 5 and none tick as correct..

Comment: how do i accept answers.I tried to search but did not find it

Comment: There is a mark tick Below the Vote button. Click on the mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values stored in ViewState work differently than session. Unlike Session, a value stored in ViewState of one page cannot be retrieved from another. Actually ViewState is nothing but a system managed hidden encrypted field in the markup produced. How do you save a value in ViewState? like this:

```
ViewState["MyValue"]=GrideView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Later you can retrieve that value like this

```
if(ViewState["MyValue"]!=null)
{
     Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx?param="+ViewState["MyValue"]);
}
```

Comment: Well, technically, you can pass and retrieve values from a ViewState across pages either by custom Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium or by using Cross-Page postback (with the help of PreviousPageType directive and PreviousPage property).